# Cocos2d and uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, cocos2d-iphone

How do I set this up in cocos2d?  I know it has to be super simple.  The part I don't understand is how do I get a reference to this in order to add it to the main cocos2d view.  I'm under the understanding that I should never subclass it...

Comment: I am an active memeber of the Cocos2d forum. Perhaps posting on the Cocos2d forum would be the best place and people with more experience.
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for presenting a GKLeaderboard within cocos2d.

```
        GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];

        UIViewController *container = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [container setView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]]; 
        [container setModalTransitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];

        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = container;

        [container presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
```

I'm sure you could adapt it to present a UINavigationController.